# EF6 Database first: Add relationship between Entities without Foreign Key Constraints

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In our current project, our team uses EntityFramework 6 with a database first approach. Due to for what the application should be used, the database doesn't use Foreign Key constraints. Is there still a way to have EntityFramework automatically map the foreign keys to the other Entities?

Here an example, right now my System model looks like this:

```
public partial class System
{
    public int SystemID { get; set; }
    public string SystemName { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}
```

With Foreign Key constraints it should look like this:

```
public partial class System
{
    public int SystemID { get; set; }
    public string SystemName { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to do this automatically or code this into the DbContext so I don't have to do the mapping by hand, every time I want to access one of the connected entities?

Comment: EF relations don't depend on FK constraints. The classes you posted don't have anything to do with FKs either. You can use both classes whether there's an FK constraint or not.

Comment: Have you tried using the second class as-is, with a `UserID` as well? The [relationship convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/conventions/built-in#relationship-convention) docs show just that, without requiring any existing constraints

Comment: What's in your `DbContext` already? Have you read the documentation on EF? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships

Comment: Change the database... by setting the foreign key constraint your problem will go away. By the way, what are we talking about? Database first or code first from database?

Comment: @grek40 It's db first, like stated in the post. And another thin stated in the post: There are good reasons why we chose no FK constraints

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your `DbContext` with the required relationship regardless of whether a foreign key exists on the actual database.

For example, the following snippet will configure a one-to-many relationship between `System` and `User`:

```
public class ExampleDbContext : DbContext
{
  public ExampleDbContext() : base("connstr") {}

  public DbSet<System> Systems { get; set; }
  public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
  
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.Entity<System>()
      .HasRequired(s => s.User)
      .WithMany(u => u.Systems)
      .HasForeignKey(s => s.UserId);
  }
}
```

Read more on the [EF6 Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships).

Comment: As far as I'm aware OnModelCreating is for Code-first approaches and not Database-first approaches, it does not get called in when one uses database first

Comment: No the `OnModelCreating` override is used to configure your model regardless of approach. See [DbContext.OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_DbContext_OnModelCreating_System_Data_Entity_DbModelBuilder_).

Comment: Well in the current configuration it is designed to throw an `UnintentionalCodeFirstException` when getting called, but I never received it. I'll give it a try tho

Comment: Think of it as a hybrid approach. You are supplementing your existing database model with more information about the structure and relationships.

Comment: With the DB First approach, it will write ```throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();``` in the OnModelCreating() method. When the program is startet that exception is never thrown, hence this place will never be "visited". So how can code, which will never be executed, change anything? Am I missing something?